# animation with react and useRef hook? is there another way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make smth like clock with react.I hope to do it with help of ref, but it doesn't work sometimes. Is there another solution of this task, or what i do wrong?

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import classes from "./Synchroniser.module.css";
const Synchroniser = () => {
    const point:any = useRef(null);
    var k = 0;
    if (point.current !== null) {
        setInterval(()=>{
                if(k<360){
                k++;
                console.log(k);
            }else{k=0}
            point.current.style.transform = `rotate(${k}deg)`;
            },100);
    }else{
        console.log(0)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <h1 ref={point}>RLY?</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Synchroniser
```

Comment: What is a smth?

Comment: @Pipe clock with hour pointer, but i need to animate it. A device what i want to create looks like clock and i want emulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Go to bottom for the pure CSS solution**

**React Solution**

This solves your problem but the k variable adds twice as much as it needs to, I don't know why. For the k variable to persist between states and not reset the clock every rerender you have to use it with useRef too.

```
  const point = useRef(null);
  const k = useRef(0);
  useEffect(() => {

    if (point.current !== null) {
    setInterval(() => {
        if (k.current < 360) {
          k.current = k.current + 1;
        } else {
          k.current = 0;
        }
        point.current.style.transform = `rotate(${k.current}deg)`;
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      console.log("0");
    }
  },[]);
```

**CSS Solution**  [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-fire-0f2fuy?file=/src/styles.css:58-910)

JSX

```
<div className="clock">
  <div className="spin"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.clock {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
.spin {
  width: 90%;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  -webkit-animation:spin 60s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 60s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 60s linear infinite;
}

.spin::after,
.spin::before {
  height: 2px;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
.spin::after {
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
.spin::before {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a strange acceleration of rotation, when i use that script do you know what's problem? follow http://sugwox.ru/ for example.  my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968434/acceleration-of-rotation-in-react-with-setinterval