# acceleration of rotation in react with setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

When i push the button it change the line on the page in accordance with position of arrow, but also i have a strange acceleration of the arrow. where is a problem?

```
element code:
    const Synchroniser = () => {
        const[result, setResult] = useState(0)
        const[word, setWord] = useState("")
        const point:any = useRef(null);
        const k = useRef(0);
    
        function calculateResult(){
            var myvar = k.current
            if (myvar<30 || myvar>330){
                setWord("YOU ARE THE BEST ELECTRICIAN")
            } else{
                setWord("try again")
            }
        }
    
        useEffect(() => {
        if (point.current !== null) {
        setInterval(() => {
            if (k.current < 360) {
              k.current = k.current + 3;
            }
            if (k.current >=360){
                k.current = 0
            }
            point.current.style.transform = `rotate(${k.current}deg)`;
          }, 10);
        } else {
          console.log("0");
        }
      });
    
        return(
            <div>
                <div className={classes.synchroniser}>
                <img src={arpng} ref={point} alt="arrow" className={classes.ar} />
                <img src={syncFrame} alt="syncframe" className={classes.syn} />
                </div>
    
                <div >
                <Button variant='contained' onClick={calculateResult}>SYNCHRONISE</Button>
                    <h1> {word} </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        );
    };
    
    export default Synchroniser
```

You can see that reaction
link: http://sugwox.ru/

Answer (score 0):

I think it relates with a manytime starts of setInterval when i render a page with different words, so i clear the interval every time:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (point.current !== null) {
    const inter = setInterval(() => {
        if (k.current < 360) {
          k.current = k.current + 5;
        }
        if (k.current >=360){
            k.current = 0
            
        }
        point.current.style.transform = `rotate(${k.current}deg)`;
      }, 10);
      return () => clearInterval(inter)
    } else {
      console.log("0");
      
    }
```